# Checking if email addresses are valid

Tags: php, email, testing

The host of the site I'm working on tends to shut off email if a certain number of fails take place. Needless to say this is a bit of a pain even if it's justified to fight spam. Is there a way to test if an email address has failed once so it can be flagged?

Comment: is your website in HTML, PHP, or ASP.NET?

Comment: @Brian: It's in PHP. Added a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send an email to the address. If it bounces back it is turned off. To check that programatically you'll need to pipe the any replies to a script that then parses the reply looking for the rejection message. Then log it in a database as being a bad address.

Answer (score 4):

+1 For John Conde, but also you could think about switching to an host who won't penalize you for this kind of problem. I understand it is Ok to fight spam, but blocking an e-mail account for a paying customer may not be the best way to achieve this, there are tons of host who won't act like this, or you could think about getting a private mail server?

Comment: +1 Hosting is such a commodity finding one without this draconian practice should be easy enough to do.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of sites send confirmation emails.  In the email it will have a code or a url that the user will use to activate their account.  Setting up your web app to do this isn't very difficult.